# Не удается подключиться к базе данных

Tags: python

```
import pyodbc 
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
                               server='DESKTOP-05A64V9\SQLEXPRESS',
                               database='Природоохранный фонд',
                               uid='1234',pwd='1234')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

**При запуске выдает ошибку**

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]При входе в систему пользователя "1234" произошла ошибка. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]При входе в систему пользователя "1234" произошла ошибка. (18456)')
```

Хотя в самой SQL Server пользователь создан и имеет доступ к базе данных

Comment: Вы пробовали [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15#additional-error-information)?

Comment: Вы, я так понимаю, в Windows? Используйте управление источниками данных ODBC для создания DSN,а потом подключайтесь при помощи него: ` connect = pyodbc.connect("DSN=ВАШ_DSN, autocommit=True") `